# How to detect redirected source page in php

Tags: php, redirect

I have two servers (Store Server and Download Server)
in Store Server After Sell Process Finished, I redirect the customer to 
a special php page in download server and he can download a file from there.

my question: in download server php, how I can determine the customer redirected from Store Server or he typed URL directly.

If any sample php exists, please put in an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i hope this will give you some idea... Good Luck.

special.php

```
<?php

/* pass some variable in special.php */
/* if your using javascript or ajax for redirection use btoa to encrypt the value */
/* or if in php use base64_encode */
/* just to avoid exposing your variable value */

if( isset( $_POST['something'] ) ){
 $something = base64_decode( $_POST['something'] );
 if( $something == 'something_you_know' ){
  echo 'redirected';
 }else{
  echo 'typed';
 }
}else{
 echo 'typed';
}

?>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer  , But i Cant send parameter. is there any way (Header Data , ...) to detect redirection

Comment: @MarryCroos No, there is no way to do that with certainty. You could only check the referrer - but that is very unreliable. If your intention is to “protect” your downloads against unauthorized access, this is not the way to go - any halfway decent download manager lets the user specify any referrer they want. You _need_ to introduce some sort of additional parameter here.